# How to expose data to the outside, with a Typescript Vue component?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

When using typescript with singlefile components, I'm having trouble to adjust the data from outside the **Vue** app.

I have a `Main.ts` where a new Vue is declared, but allocating it to a variable doesn't give me that variable available. So `var x = new Vue(){...}` in Main.ts is not working

I Tried making variables public in my `.vue` file,
I know I can select the element with `app.__vue__` but it has not variables that are declared in the .vue file, only when I initialize the variable in the `main.ts` file, I see them, but the do not get rendered by the component template.

> Main.ts:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

> App.vue script:

```
export default class App extends Vue {
  search: string = "";
}
```

When I see the JavaScript implementations, I can go from the console and adjust properties by calling th variable bound to the Vue App like `var x = new Vue() {...},` but I cant seem to get this to work in TypeScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript is a superset of JavaScript. That means it only adds to it, it doesn't remove from it. Anything you can do in JavaScript you can also do in Typescript.

That said - if you wish to access the Vue instance in a global way, you just assign it to the window:

```
(window as Window).Vue = new Vue({ 
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

^ You may have to shim that in for Typescript not to explode based on your settings.

Furthermore, variables declared with `var` are not inherently available outside the scope of the executing file. This is done on purpose as not to pollute as a global. If you really needed access to it, you could also export it from the file and import it elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, The binding works, but It doesn't make the data from the rendered single-file-component accessible yet. In the example the search field.

Comment: Ah, I found it under $children! thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

This is the eventual solution I came up with:

```
let instance = new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');

(<any>window).vueInstance = instance.$children[0];
```

now I can access my component with vue instance.